# How to set the year of a date based on value from drop down

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down that has the years basically 2011,2010,2009 etc... and there is a date that i need to append the year selected to, basically I want to check todays date

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
```

and then change the year of dt to the value selected of my drop down

`dt.Year = ddlMyYear.SelectedValue;`  but this does not work, not sure how to do this..

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DateTime` is immutable.

Instead, you can write

```
dt = new DateTime((int)ddlMyYear.SelectedValue, dt.Month, dt.Day)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this-

```
    //convert selected value to int, month can be whatever month you want 
    DateTime dtBack = new DateTime(ddlMyYear.SelectedValue, month, DateTime.Today.Day);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Use TryParse if ddlMyYear.SelectedValue could be empty or non-integer
int Year = int.Parse(ddlMyYear.SelectedValue);

DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

DateTime dt = new DateTime(Year, today.Month, today.Day);

// Use dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(ddlMyYear.SelectedValue, DateTime.Today.Month, DateTime.Today.Date)
```